# How to convert assetImage to Uint8List/File

Tags: flutter

I am trying to convert assetImage with link ("assets/image.png") into File/uint8List/

```
final ByteData byteData = await rootBundle.load(logoUrl);
final File assetLogoFile =
File("${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$logoUrl");

File markerLogoFile = await assetLogoFile.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
        .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

final Uint8List logoUint8List = await markerLogoFile.readAsBytes();
```

I am getting following error;

```
E/flutter ( 5136): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/com.example.project/cache/assets/images/flare.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
E/flutter ( 5136): #0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)
E/flutter ( 5136): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1362:47)
E/flutter ( 5136): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1265:19)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the following code to convert asset file to Uint8List;

```
 final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.jpg');
 final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
```